# How to Add directive in gulp-browserify angular project

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, gulp, browserify

I am using this code - https://github.com/rahil471/scalable-angularjs-project-setup-gulp-browserify

and it is working fine. But only issue i am facing is

that directive are not working.

**what I have done** - I added 'directive' folder inside 'componenets' in 'src', It is creating a copy of 'directive' in component of 'public' perfectly but it is showing app in not defined.
i Created custom.js file inside 'directive' folder and included it in index.html(outer most).

**custom.js**

```
app.directive('mydir', function() {
   return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<h1>ANIL</h1>'
    };
});
```

added  in about.html in 'component' in 'src'

Code is copied to about.html in 'component' in 'public' perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty bad explanation of issue but let's try to figure it out. So you want to create additional directive? If that's the case then you have to include directive folder (and files) inside app.js (src/app/app.js) like this:

```
require('./components/directive/custom.js');
```

Browserify will then know to include this file into main bundle and app will recognize your directive.

And don't include anything inside index file, browserify and gulp will make everything ready for you.